How to use Curl with credentials in PHP
Trying to use curl to call api response.
The only documentation is this:
https://stage-sgf-partner-api.azurewebsites.net/api/swagger/ui#/Person/PartnerApi_Person_GetGolferInfoByGolfId
I have ClientId and Password to use for the server.
This is the error message from server.
"Failed to load API definition.
Errors
Fetch error
NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. https://stage-sgf-partner-api.azurewebsites.net/api/swagger.json
Fetch error
Possible cross-origin (CORS) issue? The URL origin (https://stage-sgf-partner-api.azurewebsites.net) does not match the page (https://www.systemtest.the18club.se). Check the server returns the correct 'Access-Control-Allow-*' headers."
Any suggestions what can be wrong?
$username='xxxxx';
$password='xxxxx';
$URL='https://stage-sgf-partner-api.azurewebsites.net/api/swagger/ui#/Person/PartnerApi_Person_GetGolferInfoByGolfId=114973-122';
    
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
    
curl_close ($ch);


URL is wrong, you copied documentation link instead the API link which is like this: https://stage-sgf-partner-api.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/Persons/GetGolferInfoByGolfId?golfID=1

You are right! Now i got this message instead "{"TechnicalMessage":"Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.","Type":"Sgf.Unauthorized"} ", not sure about how to use my credentials. They sent me ClientID: xxxx and a password.

then you need to authorize yourself first, there must be another documentation where its described how to do that

@Johannes Maybe you need to use this?

Ok, first time i use Curl so i´m sorry for my stupid questions. Should i first send request with my credentials and then recieve a Token or how does this works.

@Johannes Yes, you should probably do that (then use the token in subsequent requests). However, all of this should be properly documented somewhere, instead of you having to guess it.

The people that built the API tells me the credentials should be sent in the body. But this code below response "invalid credentials"
$data = json_encode(array(
'ClientId'  => 'xxxxx',
'ClientSecret' => 'xxxxx'
));
    
$URL='https://stage-sgf-partner-api.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/Authentication/Tokens';
    
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print_r($result);

What can be wrong?
Update:
The problem is that the payload should look like this:
{
"ClientId": "xxxx",
"ClientSecret": "xxxx",
}
but instead my payload looks something like this:
-------------18b06fbcf12fd14 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ClientId" xxxx ----------------18b06fbcf12fd14 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ClientSecret" xxxx ----------------18b06fbcf12fd14

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
